# New Azure Setup - Can't Login

Tags: azure, authentication

For some reason, new Azure setup and it "looks" like it's using a my domain.onmicrosoft.com but I'm not sure what to use as the login and password.

It defaults to my MicrosoftAccount\username@outlook.com even though I'm using my work one which is mydomain.onmicrosoft.com.

Sorry for the remedial question but challenging to test something I can't even login in to the RD with.

Comment: What or where is it defaulting incorrectly?  I.e. are you in the Azure Portal and not seeing the account you expect?  Or are you not able to login to the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0):

step by step guide to microsoft azure account setup detais [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/blainbar/archive/2012/09/10/step-by-step-setting-up-windows-azure-for-the-first-time-and-creating-a-vm-role-of-windows-server-2012-on-microsoft-s-public-cloud.aspx) [link1](http://www.rebeladmin.com/2015/05/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-windows-azure-active-directory-part-02/)